# Invoke ant from java, then return to java after ant termination

Tags: java, ant

so far i have invoked ant script from java. Now the question is, is it possible to resume java execution after the termination of the ant build?

How do i do it?

Comment: Does you java program terminate when ant is done? Or do you mean how to wait for ant to complete before continuing?

Comment: Could you please post the actual code that *invokes ant script from java?*

Answer (score 3):

`org.apache.tools.ant.Main`'s `main()` and `startAnt()` methods call the `exit()` method which in turn calls `System.exit(code)`.

The solution (assuming you call one of those methods) is to sub-class  `org.apache.tools.ant.Main` and override the `exit()` method

```
/**
 * This operation is expected to call {@link System#exit(int)}, which
 * is what the base version does.
 * However, it is possible to do something else.
 * @param exitCode code to exit with
 */
protected void exit(int exitCode) {
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the source of Ant's main class, [`org.apache.tools.ant.Main`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/Main.java?view=co). You can try to invoke its `main` or `start` method directly, or copy some of its logic to your application. <del>After those methods finish, your application should continue execution.</del>

**EDIT:**

[The answer by Paul Cager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8715524/232235) is correct, I somehow missed the fact that Ant's `Main` calls `System.exit()`.

Another thing about the `main`/`start`/`startAnt` methods is that they expect the arguments as an array of strings. This can be handy, but it's not particularly typesafe or object-oriented. To invoke Ant for a given buildfile and target, you can use something like this:

```
public static void runAnt(String buildfile, String target) throws Exception {
    File buildFile = new File(buildfile);
    Exception error = null;
    org.apache.tools.ant.Project project = new org.apache.tools.ant.Project();
    try {
        project.addBuildListener(new org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener());
        project.fireBuildStarted();
        project.init();
        project.setUserProperty(org.apache.tools.ant.MagicNames.ANT_FILE, buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(project, buildFile);
        project.executeTarget(target);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e;
        throw e;
    } finally {
        project.fireBuildFinished(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Process p = Runtme.getRuntime.exec("ant mytarget");
p.waitFor();  // waits until process completes before continuing to next line
// continue Java program here
```